# Proper insert of date in MySql date field

Tags: php, mysql

I am posting data for event in this format via ajax:

```
doctor=100&date=2015-04-30&rCheck=1&rDate=2015-05-12&fromTime=21%3A35&toTime=22%3A40&status=open
```

I am getting it like this with php

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
$fromHours = $_POST['fromHours'];
$fromMinutes = $_POST['fromMinutes'];
$toHours = $_POST['toHours'];
$toMinutes = $_POST['toMinutes'];
$fromTime = $_POST['fromTime'];
$toTime = $_POST['toTime'];
$start = $date.' '.$fromTime.':00';
$end = $date.' '.$toTime.':00';
$status = $_POST['status'];
$doctor = $_POST['doctor'];

if($_POST['rCheck']==1){
    $repeat = $_POST['rDate'];
}else{
    $repeat = '0000-00-00';
}
```

When I echo any of that variables I get correct result.

I am inserting data in database like this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO events (start,end,doctor,status,repeat) VALUES ("'.$start.'","'.$end.'","'.$doctor.'","'.$status.'","'.$repeat.'")';
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die (mysqli_error($db));
```

Now main problem is `$repeat` because without it everything is inserted without problem but with `$repeat` I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'repeat) VALUES ("2015-04-30 21:35:00","2015-04-30 22:40:00","100","offen","2015-' at line 1

Insert stops after fifth '-' character. Even if `$repeat` is `0000-00-00`
Field for that in database is date field in format `0000-00-00`
I really don't know where problem is.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Have you tried to output the contents of your query to make sure your expected interpolated variables are kicking out the correct value?  Output `$query` to see the actual (full) statement being sent to the DB instead of what you are being shown in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeat` is a MySQL reserved word

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Either rename it to something else; for example "repeats", or use ticks around it

```
(start,end,doctor,status,`repeat`)
```

Look at what MySQL is telling you; it's pointing it out where it starts:

```
...for the right syntax to use near 'repeat  
                                    ^
```

---

**Sidenote:**

- If you're still having problems inserting data into your table, you can sanitize your input(s) using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or using prepared statements as stated below.

---

- I need to point out though, that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
  Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.